# Angular 2 webpack export/import issue

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an angular 2 webpack project which I am sharing with another developer. On his machine, webpack compiling works fine but on mine I get an error

**node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported member 'ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS'**

I've checked in index.d.ts and his one is different. We're totally baffled as to why.

Any more information I can give to clarify, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you imported it in your angular2 bootstrap file (usually main.ts), you can probably remove it.
The change occured between rc1 and 4 and does not seem to exist in rc4.
I encountered the same issue when upgrading my app from rc1 to rc4.

[Source here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9769)

Comment: Thanks. Had already reached this conclusion after a while searching around.